# Why is Opera browser in version 12.16 for Linux and version 22 for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, opera

I noticed that Opera browser is in version 12.16 for Linux  version 22 for Windows.

Why is there such a dramatic difference in version numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera 22 is not the Opera you know and love. It is a completely different program, contains no old Opera code and is based on the Google Chrome codebase.

The original Presto-based Opera has been discontinued after version 12. It is still supported for security fixes, but no new features will be added and websites may get borked.

Comment: Yup, Opera 12.17 is available for windows too, you just have to find it in the downloads section. Its a bit hidden on the opera website. But it is so much better than opera 22. Opera 22 still misses a lot of the cool features 12.17 has.

Comment: @LPChip Completely agree. Opera 12 is the only Android browser that allows me to disable rescaling of images, and i use it to this day.

Comment: Actually, Opera and Chrome use a fork of WebKit called Blink.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with [Opera 24](http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/06/opera-24-linux-released-developer-stream/) you'll get a [Linux Build](http://www.opera.com/download/get/?partner=www&opsys=Linux&product=Opera%20Developer) again. But as *@kinokijuf* said, this new version is completely based on Chromium Code and has nothing to do with the old Opera.